# CodeDeploy events not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

This is how my CodeDeploy status looks like:
[image]

[image]

This is first time I'm trying to set this up. I created EC2 and added following policies to attached IAM role:
[image]

and edited Trust relationships like this:

[image]

also I installed code deploy agent on EC2 instance.

this is my appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: .
    destination: /home/ubuntu
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 5
      runas: root
```

stop_server.sh is just an empty file

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem you're facing is that the agent either isn't installed or the instance doesn't have sufficient permissions. When there are no events started on the instance for the deployment, it means that CodeDeploy couldn't talk to the host for some reasons.

Here's the steps I would take:

1. [Confirm that you installed the CodeDeploy agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html)
2. [Confirm that you've created the IAM service role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html)
3. [Confirm that you have the IAM Instance Profile and that it's associated with the instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html)
4. Check that you can reach the CodeDeploy commands endpoint in your region from the box. i.e. `ping codedeploy.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` Otherwise, your networking setup might be too restrictive.
5. [Look at the logs on the host to see what's going on](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html)